# Alterar a senha de um usuário no Django, e verificar se os dados fornecidos estão corretos

Tags: html, python, aplicação-web, django

Estou trabalhando em um projeto em Django a fim didaticos e estou com problema para alteração de senha de usuário no Django.

No entanto já consegui alterar a senha atraves de um formulário como abaixo:

Essas são minhas views:

```
def password(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
   username = request.POST.get('username')
   email = request.POST.get('email')
   novasenha = request.POST.get('novasenha')

       user = User.objects.get(username=username)
       user.set_password(novasenha)
       user.save()
       messages.success(request,'Senha alterada com sucesso!')
   else:
       messages.success(request, 'Dados errados')
       return render(request,'password_form.html')

return render(request,'password_form.html')
```

Esse é meu formulário, onde as views pegam os valores:

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>Usuário</label>
        <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        <br>
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" name="email"><br>
        <br>
        <label>Nova Senha</label>
        <input type="password" name="novasenha"><br>
        <br>
    <button type="submit">SALVAR</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Sendo assim, altero a senha do usuário, mas não verifico se os dados estão corretos, como posso implementar isso? obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para verificar se o utilizador existe pode usar o try:

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
except user.DoesNotExist:
    messages.success(request, 'Dados errados')
    return render(request,'password_form.html')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -2):

Não entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas digamos que o usuário esteja logado na área do user e quer mudar a senha por qualquer motivo,
você precisa analisar todos os dados inclusive a senha antiga.

```
try:
  user = User.objects.get(username=username, email=email)
  if user.check_password(senhaantiga):
     user.set_password(senhanova)
     messages.success(request, 'Senha modificada com sucesso!')
  else:
     messages.error(request, 'A senha antiga não esta correta')

except User.DoesNotExist:
   messages.error(request, 'Usuario não encontrado!')
```

Genericamente falando é isto!